# applying css class to menu item at run time in mvc

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am working on an MVC4 Application

I have a following Menu Items

```
<ul class="menu left">
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", new { Controller = "Home" }, new { @class = "active" })</li>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("About Us", "About", new { Controller = "Home" })</li>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Services", "Services", new { Controller = "Home" })</li>      
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Post Job", "Create", new { Controller = "JobPosting" })</li>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Job Search", "Index", new { Controller = "JobPosting" })</li>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contact Us", "Contact", new { Controller = "Home" })</li>
           </ul>
```

Now I want if I click on Items other than Home, its  css-class changes to active.
Basically I just want to change the color of the menu-item
How can I make this dynamically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to change the css based on Action or Controller you can use

```
@{
    var controller = ViewContext.RouteData.Values["Controller"].ToString();
    var action = ViewContext.RouteData.Values["Action"].ToString();
}

<li> 
    @if (action == "Home") { 
       @Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", new { Controller = "Home" },new {@class="active" })
    }
    else {
       @Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", new { Controller = "Home" })
    }
</li>
<li>
   @if (action == "About Us") { 
           @Html.ActionLink("About Us", "About", new { Controller = "Home" },new {@class="active" })
        }
        else {
           @Html.ActionLink("About Us", "About", new { Controller = "Home" })
        }
</li>
```

etc...

Comment: this works but it is bad. too much logic in view and code duplication

Comment: yeah it is was just showing him how it can be done should be refactored

Comment: Thanks K.A.G , It did the trikc

Answer (score 0):

```
public static class MyHtmlHelper
{
    public static String NavActive(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, 
                          string actionName, 
                          string controllerName)
    {
        var controller = htmlHelper.ViewContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("controller");
        var action = htmlHelper.ViewContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("action");

        if (controllerName == controller && action == actionName )
            return "active";
        else
            return String.Empty;
    }
}
```

Then you can use this helper in your view.

```
@Html.NavActive("Index", "Home")
```

For instance,

```
<li>
    <a href="~/Home/Index" class="@Html.NavActive("Index", "Home")">
        <span>Index</span>
    </a>
</li>
```