# changing menu color on click is not working properly in jquery mvc

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using Following Menu with `<ul> and <li>s`

```
<ul class="menu">

                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", new { Controller = "Home" })</li> @*, new { @class = "active" }*@
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("About Us", "About", new { Controller = "Home" })</li>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Services", "Services", new { Controller = "Home" })</li>      
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Post Job", "Create", new { Controller = "JobPosting" })</li>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Job Search", "Index", new { Controller = "JobPosting" })</li>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contact Us", "Contact", new { Controller = "Home" })</li>
               </ul>
```

I am Using Following Javascript method

```
function ApplySelectClassOnMenu() {    
var url = window.location.pathname;
var index = url.lastIndexOf('/');
if (index > 0) {
    url = url.substring(index);
}
$('.menu >li').each(function () {        
    var url1 = $(this).children().attr("href");
    index = url1.lastIndexOf('/');
    if (index > 0) {
        url1 = url1.substring(index);
    }
    if (url1 == url) {            
        $(this).children().addClass('active');
    }
    else {
        $(this).children().removeClass('active');
    }
});
```

}

and calling it on `document.ready` as

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function () {
         ApplySelectClassOnMenu();
     });
```

**Now here problem comes, Colour of menu item does get changed but if you

- don't keep mouse on menu item(`<li>`item) for few seconds
- don't drag your mouse to that `<li>` item, if you give url directly in address bar

Colour remain same and is not changed

**

Can anyone help me in resolving this Issue?????

Comment: See this answer to one of my questions for how to do this on the server: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1231527/144496

Comment: Thanks @Martin I have already done this on the server. I want to do it on client side with jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end had to stick with server side method as @Martin suggested,

[applying css class to menu item at run time in mvc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14771121/applying-css-class-to-menu-item-at-run-time-in-mvc)